# Tutorial for libsvm c++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Looking for tutorials and/or sample code for libSVM's C++ interface.
Specifically, I want to classify features extracted by using SIFT or SURF feature descriptors.

I have tried looking on the website and did not find any such documentation/sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIBSVM site gives some links to examples and tutorials:

- http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/
- http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/otherdocuments/index.html

Specifically, C example are located here:

- http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/string/

Comment: That C link is dead.